# Create progressbar from values in array

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to dynamically create progress bars based on information I put in variables. This, however isn't working :/ (I'm a noob still)
Can someone take a look and perhaps tell me what's wrong?

```
$skills = array("HTML & CSS:" => $htmlcss, 
            "Bootstrap:" => $bootstrap, 
            "PHP & MySql:" => $phpmysql, 
            "jQuery & JavaScript:" => $jqueryjavascript); 
$arrLen = array_count_values($skills);

//foreach($skills as $x => $x_value) 
while($x <= $arrLen) 
{
    echo "
        <p>$key</p>
        <div class='progress'>
            <div class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped active' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow=$value aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: $value %>
            </div>
        </div> 
    ";
    $x++;
}
```

Old code:

```
<?php

$htmlcss = 80;
$bootstrap = 70;
$phpmysql = 50;
$jqueryjavascript = 5;

$skills = array("HTML & CSS:" => $htmlcss, 
            "Bootstrap:" => $bootstrap, 
            "PHP & MySql:" => $phpmysql, 
            "jQuery & JavaScript:" => $jqueryjavascript); 
$arrLen = array_count_values($skills);

foreach($skills as $x => $x_value)
{
    echo "
        <p>$x</p>
        <div class='progress'>
            <div class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped active' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow=$x_value aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: $x_value %>
            </div>
        </div> 
    ";
}
echo "Done";
```

?>

Comment: You need the foreach loop to get the current progress $x_value

Comment: The foreach loop has been disabled, not using the $x_value. I did try using the foreach loop with $x and $x_value, but that resulted in errors as well.

Not on my pc right now, so I can't copy/paste the errors, will do so when I get home in a couple of hours.

Comment: Was there something wrong with the `foreach` you've commented out? Also, you're echoing variable `$key` which isn't initialized anywhere.

Comment: The foreach didn't work, I got a lot of errors, so I tried other ways to accomplish my goal. 
As I said in my original post, I am a noob ^_^
Trying my best to get better at it though!!

Comment: I changed my code back to what I had before (view the original post above ^). This create the name HTML & CSS for the progress bar and the bar itself, but not the "filling".
Also, it just creates one bar, instead of 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like invalid html/css. 
The HTML code is missing appropriate wrapping quotes on your div attributes.

Also `width: $x_value %` is not valid since it would result as `width: 80 %` which is invalid style. It should be `width: $x_value%`

Lastly unless your entire website uses single quotes, you should conform to using double quotes in your HTML created by PHP. Mixing single and double quotes may appear correctly in some browsers, while others will render it incorrectly ([W3C Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2)).

You can use [NOWDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) or [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) style of strings, to easily use double or single quotes along with variables, when outputting HTML using PHP.

```
<?php
$htmlcss = 80;
$bootstrap = 70;
$phpmysql = 50;
$jqueryjavascript = 5;
$skills = [
    'HTML & CSS:' => $htmlcss,
    'Bootstrap:' => $bootstrap,
    'PHP & MySql:' => $phpmysql,
    'jQuery & JavaScript:' => $jqueryjavascript
]; //PHP 5.4 array syntax
foreach($skills as $x => $x_value) {
    echo <<<EOL
    <p>$x</p>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="$x_value" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: $x_value%">
        </div>
    </div> 
EOL;
}
```

Result:

[image: Progress Bars]

Comment: Thank you, this worked!
I learned a lot from this, and I will try to understand all of the code you showed me.